# What is a light-weight alternative to ocamlyacc/menhir for parsing simple expression?

Tags: ocaml

I have a data type of very simple algebraic expressions (with only identifiers, addition, and multiplication), and I want to parse strings such as "a + b * (c + d)" into this type.  My default impulse would be to use Ulex+Menhir, but I wonder if there is not a simpler solution for such a simple problem.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream parser? http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/tutorial-camlp4/tutorial002.html

and Genlex for scanner http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Genlex.html

Comment: You could also just hand-code a recursive descent parser.  This isn't too different from a stream parser, but doesn't require campl4.

Answer (score 4):

You could DIY. [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/1764314) that handles the case you want. Note that the style is not quite functional and basically taken from [this Wikipedia page on recursive descent parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser#C_implementation). The equivalent ocamllex/ocamlyacc parser would be a lot more concise and readable (and performant? not sure!).

Comment: If you care about giving meaningful parse error messages to your users that's definitively the way to go. And if you care about long term maintenance of your parser steer away from stream parsers.